# webview back button stopped

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, dom-events

In my webview app if I press the back button I get an error:

> *unfortunately app has stopped*

I've tried 2 different ways of doing the back button. Am I missing something?

P.s. first app so please bear with me

```
package au.com.industryresponsetraining.mdt;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mwebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String "http://www.google.com";
        WebView mwebview = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mwebview.loadUrl(url);
        mwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    private class MyWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://www.google.com")) {
                return false;
            } else {
                //here open external links in external browser or app
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
//back button function thats not working
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mwebview.canGoBack()) {
            mwebview.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your stack trace

Comment: I have no idea what that is ?

Comment: Dont have a crash log

Comment: @shaggs   you gave two reference to mwebview , one is global and one is in onCreate method. remove the onCreate method reference

Comment: @Aasvi as im new to droid programming can you point to to the onCreate method reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your onCreate method should be

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String "http://www.google.com";
    mwebview = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

}
```

instead of

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String "http://www.google.com";
    WebView mwebview = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

}
```

Comment: Is it just me or are these identical?

Comment: @shaggs check once, you define local reference also in this method.

Comment: Haha it just changed as sent comment will try now

Comment: @shaggs I am not sure but try.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mwebview.canGoBack()) {
                    mwebview.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```